# JSRuntime is not registered Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I have a Blazor Wasm project and when I want to inject the JSRuntime

```
@inject JSRuntime js
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot provide a value for property 'js' on type 'BlazorApp.Pages.Page'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime'

Is JSRuntime not registered by default?

How do I register it?

Comment: Use IJSRuntime instead of  JSRuntime

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to inject `IJSRuntime`, not `JSRuntime`.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

and in method use `JSRuntime` as object with methods.